# Why is an integer argument passed to die() not printed?

Tags: php

Why do I get output of `60` from `die()` for this:

```
$min = $row['min'];
die($min);
```

But not for this?

```
$min = $row['min']*60;
die($min);
```

Comment: try casting the `$row['min']` to an int

Comment: Because something else is wrong but you haven't shown it.  You need to provide a code example that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: `$row['min']` must be a string.  Performing the multiplication converts it to an integer, which is then treated as a status code in `die()`.  "If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed"

Comment: You are right. If you `print_r($min)` and `die()` after i get my result.

Comment: I cleaned up the question and the code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

If you need the value even if it's a number, parse it to string with [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php):

```
die(strval($min));
```

---

**Documentation**

According to [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php), it's an *Equivalent to exit*.

In [Exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) we can see that it has two signatures:

```
void exit ( int $status )
```

And

```
void exit ([ string $status ] )
```

Both are described below:

> If status is an **integer**, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

And

> If status is a **string**, this function prints the status just before exiting.

*(emphasis mine)*

---

**Elaborating**

In the first code example from your question, `$row['min']` is most likely just a string (eg `string(2) "70"`). When you multiply it by a number, PHP 'casts' the value to a number so it can multiply.

So, in the first example, it's calling the `exit ([ string $status ] )` function, which *prints the status just before exiting*.
In the second example, it's calling the `exit ( int $status )` function, which *will be used as the exit status and not printed.*

If you want to see it for yourself, use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and check the variables types. [Check an Example](https://eval.in/887925).

Answer (score 2):

It is because you should pass a string: "Required. Specifies the message or status number to write before exiting the script. The status number will not be written to the output."
After multiplying the value is casted to int type and therefore die will not print it.

Answer (score 1):

The `die()` function is an alias of [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

PHP's documentation states that `exit()` is [polymorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). That is, it can accept both strings or integers as its only argument.

When you provide a string, it is printed before the script exits.

When you provide an integer (between `0-254`), it is used as the script's [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) and nothing is printed. A code of `0` denotes successful completion of the script, and anything else is an error.  The code `255` is reserved by PHP.

You can use `strval()` or `intval()` to ensure you are passing the right data type for your needs.